# Is it possible to recover the Referrer in doFilter function of a filter in tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a filter to display the http request headers:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        Enumeration headers = req.getHeaderNames();
        for (; headers.hasMoreElements(); ) {

            String name = (String) headers.nextElement();
            String value = req.getHeader(name);
            LOGGER.info("- " + name + " = " + value);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Using firebug I can see the following request headers:

```
Host    mydomain.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language es-es,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer http://mydomain.com/test/index.html
```

But the filter only shows me this:

```
16:39:49,064  INFO RefererFilter:42 - - user-agent = Java/1.5.0_22
16:39:49,064  INFO RefererFilter:42 - - host = mydomain.com
16:39:49,064  INFO RefererFilter:42 - - accept = text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
16:39:49,064  INFO RefererFilter:42 - - connection = keep-alive
16:39:49,064  INFO RefererFilter:42 - - content-length = 0
```

I need to look at the referer header, but I do not know why the filter does not display. "I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: how are you testing this? It's odd that your headers appear as all lower-case.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if Tomcat is put behind a proxy which swallows this header. This problem is not solvable from the Java/Tomcat side on. You need to solve it at the proxy side.

The `user-agent = Java/1.5.0_22` is by the way suspicious. Is it a homegrown proxy/client which utilizes `java.net.URLConnection` or something?

Comment: All in the same tomcat and we do not have a proxy. I am using tomcat 5.5 and java 1.5.0_22

Comment: It's technically possible to have a proxy filter which is mapped on `/*`. The headers which you retrieved suggests that you were using `URLConnection` to send the requests instead of a normal webbrowser.

Comment: The request I do it for Ajax via a javascript library called OpenLayers.